Evolving mood and aspect from the same auxiliaries?
I know for one of my languages I want there to be a realis vs. irrealis distinction in the verb paradigm - but I'm not entirely sure how to get there.
In Routes towards the irrealis (Andrea Sansò, 2020), Sansò says that irrealis markers can arise from a number of auxiliary verbs, such as "to go" and "to be".
(I... do not really understand his explanation for why these would yield an irrealis meaning - yes, he explains that e.g. "to go" would first yield an itive/distal meaning, and then that distal yields a optative-desiderative, but that second step feels like a non sequitur; why would a distal yield an optative? But, sure, I'll accept it.)
The problem this causes is that I was already using those same auxiliary verbs to derive aspect - e.g. "to go" for imperfective (which turns into the present), and "to be" for stative → perfect aspect.
Hmm... maybe it could be both at once? The construction including "to go" could be both imperfective (→ present) and irrealis? But then I still need a way to express the realis present. (And, you know, irrealis in all the other tenses/aspects)
Enter an idea from Kabardian - explicitly marking verbs realis, and assuming irrealis if not:

After inflectional tense comes mood, which can be either the various mood suffixes or any non-finite morphemes. Moods denote affirmative declarative, negative, irrealis (including optatives and hortatives), interrogative, and imperative (for the jussive see (199)). Kabardian appears to be unique in the world in having a distinct mood mark for simple positive declaratives (in all but the present active tense), /-ś/ (perhaps underlyingly /-śa/ (225e)). Absence of this affirmative creates a neutral irrealis (220h) (Dumezil 1975: 101, §35), or a simple interrogative (220i).
-John Colarusso, A Grammar of Kabardian (1992), p.125, section 4.2.7.4.2

I don't know what a realis marker could evolve from. Intuitively, probably a resultative marker or something. But again, I was already using a resultative marker to derive an aspect, this time perfective aspect (→ aorist past). cf. The Evolution of Language: Tense, Aspect, and Modality in the Languages of the World (Bybee et al., 1994), Section 3.7.
I mean honestly, having some tenses be default-realis and others be default-irrealis seems kind of cool; I'm just getting confused how to pull it off without getting in my own way and interfering with the existing origins for verbal aspect, as I currently am.
What do?

You could just use "to want" for an irrealis - it's a pretty basic concept and what you want to be true isn't necessarily true

There's also the fact that English uses "to be" for both the passive voice and the progressive aspect. The difference? The form of the main verb - the passive uses the past participle and the progressive uses the present participle
